# SQLPlus batch file - how to return to command prompt?

Tags: oracle, batch-file, sqlplus

I'm trying to export an Oracle table to a text file. I have that working, but I also need to copy the text file from one location to another after the export is over. After the SELECT statement, how can I go from the `SQL>` prompt back to a `C:\` prompt?

I have a batch file, select.bat, that does this:

```
echo @d:\users\myusername\desktop\sqlscript.sql | sqlplus mylogin/mypassword
```

and sqlscript.sql looks like this:

```
set colsep ,
set pagesize 0
set trimspool on
set headsep off
set linesize 9999
spool d:\users\myusername\desktop\tablename.csv
select * from tablename;
spool off
```

I run the batch file and everything works great. How can I add a line like:

```
move d:\users\myusername\desktop\tablename.csv "\\server\share\myfolder\"
```

either in the .bat file or in the .sql file?

Thanks!

UPDATE:

I changed the batch file to this:

```
start cmd.exe /k "sqlplus mylogin/mypassword @d:\users\myusername\desktop\sqlscript.sql & move /y d:\users\jjb4211\desktop\tablename.csv \\servername\sharename\myfolder & exit"
```

and in the SQl file I added `exit` after `spool off`

So now I can run the .bat file, it opens a new command prompt, connects to Oracle, spools the table to a text file, moves the text file to the network, and exits.

Comment: I think you need to add `exit` to the SQL Script. Then your batch file should continue after calling SQL*Plus

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I tried adding `exit` after the `spool off` line, but it closes the command prompt window (instead of just exiting sqlplus and returning to c:\).

Comment: Well if you double-click the batch file, then this is the expected behaviour: once the batch file is finished the command line window is closed unless you started the batch file by typing its name manually in the command line.

Comment: That makes sense. I changed that batch file to `start cmd.exe /K "echo @d:\users\myusername\desktop\sqlscript.sql | sqlplus mylogin/mypassword"` and in the SQL script I added `exit` to the end. This runs the SQL script and keeps the command prompt window open afterwards. Now I just need to add my `Move` statement after the `exit` line and I think I'll be set. Thank you! If you want to post your comments as an answer I'll go ahead and accept it.

Comment: The `move` statement needs to go into the .bat file (after the call to sqlplus) not into the SQL script

Answer (score 0):

'/' after exit will terminate script and return to batch file. Put exit and / at the end of sql script:

set colsep ,;

set pagesize 0;

set trimspool on;

set headsep off;

set linesize 9999;

spool d:\tablename.csv;

select * from robmat.rdok;

spool off;

exit;

/

Now it works with your initial batch file where you will put move command in second line.